# Angular 2 Universal - Server Side Rendering with stylus and pug template

Tags: angular, webpack, angular2-universal

I am trying to build an app with Angular2, typescript, stylus (for css), and pug (for html templating).

But, I can't make it work with Angular2 Universal.

The problem is that I'm using `ts-node` to run my server code and whenever I import my App component, an error occurs.

## server.ts (node/express):

```
import 'angular2-universal/polyfills';

import * as path from 'path';
import * as express from 'express';
import * as bodyParser from 'body-parser';


// Angular 2 Universal
import {
  provide,
  enableProdMode,
  expressEngine,
  REQUEST_URL,
  ORIGIN_URL,
  BASE_URL,
  NODE_ROUTER_PROVIDERS,
  NODE_HTTP_PROVIDERS,
  ExpressEngineConfig
} from 'angular2-universal';

// Application
import {App} from './app/modules/app';
```

The error occurs:

> app/modules/app/app.styl:2   margin-bottom: 10px
>                  ^ SyntaxError: Unexpected token :

## app.ts

```
import {Component, ViewEncapsulation} from '@angular/core';
import {RouteConfig, Router, ROUTER_DIRECTIVES} from '@angular/router-deprecated';

import {Home} from '../home';


/*
 * App Component
 * Top Level Component
 */
@Component({
  selector:      'app',
  pipes:         [ ],
  providers:     [ ],
  directives:    [ ],
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None,
  styles:        [
    require('./app.styl')
  ],
  template: require('./app.pug')
})
```

## app.styl

```
input
  margin-bottom: 10px
```

The alternative is to run the build code (generated by webpack). But how can I do that, since the code is wrapped by `webpackjsonp` function.

Comment: It would be helpful if you made a [runnable example](http://code.runnable.com) of your code.

Answer (score 0):

You can use stylus using precompilation: stylus -> css -> `styles: [require(.css)]`.

Templates could be also precompiled or handled like this:

```
function compile(template:string)
{
      pug.compile(template, {});
}

//component definition
template: compile(require('template.pug'))
```